# How does cyclic voltammetry in a electrolytic cell measure the precise oxidation potential?

Tags: electrochemistry, cyclic-voltammetry

From what I understand, the potential necessary to induce a current to flow in an electrolytic cell depends on both reduction potentials of the anode and cathode reactions, where *E(cell)* is comprised of these two potentials and determines the spontaneity of the reaction, and hence the current flow. Thus, in cyclic voltammetry in an electrolytic setup, wouldn't the anodic redox potential thus depend on the cathodic redox potential?

As in, the position of a peak potential at a certain point in a cyclic voltammogram would change depending on what is reduced at the cathode in an electrolytic cell, because a change in the redox potential of the cathode changes the required voltage to induce spontaneous current flow from the anode to the cathode.